# Ubuntu partition structure - can someone just paste me their df -m?

Tags: partitioning, 18.04

I just installed Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 (having problems already), and it doesn't put /home in a seperate partition.

Does normal Ubuntu do that?  I can't remember.

So anyway can someone running normal Ubuntu with the default partitioning structure paste me your:

```
df -m
```

Comment: Normal Ubuntu has just two partitions `/dev/sda2 on /` root and `/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi` so it's normal!

Comment: If you want a specific partition [scheme], use 'something else' & partition yourself, so you get exactly what you want.  It's always my choice.